# Motor shaft mounting with clamps and bushings

Tags: motors, coupling

If I'm in the wrong section of stack exchange, please help me go to the right place.

I am trying to find out if this combination of motor shaft and clamps will work out.

I found these clamps/bushings

https://www.maedler.de/product/1643/1621/spannsaetze-com-b-bohrung-6-bis-100mm

and I'm curious if they will work out with the kind of shaft on this motor

http://mehatron.rs/step-motor-nema-34-86x155-60a-130nm-sa-duplom-osovinom

The main problem is that the shaft of that motor is machined and the clamp relies on the full surface of the shaft.

By the way, those clamps work for the motors with a shaft containing removable key ( for example MiGE 130ST-M15015 ).

Aliexpress is full of these shaft couplings, but i do not believe that they are sufficient to hold these kinds of torque levels, for example :

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32967906911.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.2f2c46a1ZWZH4p&algo_pvid=0a5001e7-7d75-4397-9a01-0e5d64cde7cd&algo_expid=0a5001e7-7d75-4397-9a01-0e5d64cde7cd-9&btsid=deae1df8-64c1-479e-9d65-e967ef04e93f&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_8,searchweb201603_53

or these :

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32956726953.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.2f2c46a1ZWZH4p&algo_pvid=0a5001e7-7d75-4397-9a01-0e5d64cde7cd&algo_expid=0a5001e7-7d75-4397-9a01-0e5d64cde7cd-8&btsid=deae1df8-64c1-479e-9d65-e967ef04e93f&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_8,searchweb201603_53

The good thing about these sahft couplers is that they can be made to fir the shaft perfectly, with 2 screws for the 2 machined parts i was talking about.

The forces are around 10 Nm and I want to avoid any kind of slipping.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to engineering.SE

Comment: What are you trying to attach to the motor? Sometimes this helps guide the bushing selection process.

Comment: @jko I want to attach a steering wheel with 70mm bolt pattern, those are standard car racing wheels. An adapter would be needed between the clamp/coupler/bushing and the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to say that no, your chosen coupling would not work.  Based on the K-K cross-section in the drawing, there would be a large portion of the shaft that is not in contact with the coupling.

I believe what you need is a coupling where it is held against a flat in the shaft by a set screw, like the one here (though in your size):  https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/shaft-coupling/5mm-6mm-flexible-coupling-18x25mm-cnc-stepper-motor-shaft-coupler-st-fc02.html

You will need to match your torque requirements to the coupling as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A big problem is the mentioned torque rating. Those coupling are pretty weak, the toughest one that i saw maxed around 4 Nm. Is there any alternative that you can think of?